# Send $element as parameter to external function Directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following directive.js

```
angular.module('myDirective',[])

.directive('inputBox',function(){
    return{
        restrict:"E",
        controller:['$scope','$element',function($scope,$element){
            $scope.printMessage = function(){
                $scope.inputval = 'Enter input here';
                var myelem = $element;
                console.log(myelem[0]);
                return $scope.onButtonClicked({widgetEvent:$element});
            };
        }],
        scope:{
            buttonName:"@",
            printedMessage:"@",
            onButtonClicked:"&"
        },
        template:'<input type="text" ng-model="inputval"><button ng-click="printMessage()">{{buttonName}}</button>'
    };
})
```

This is my HTML:

```
My Directive: <input-Box button-Name="Click Me!!" on-button-clicked="showAlertMessage(widgetEvent)"><input-Box>
```

I have App.js module like this:

```
angular.module('myApp',['myDirective'])
.controller('myController',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.showAlertMessage = function(e){
        alert('this is a alert');
        console.log(e);
    };
}]);
```

i want to pass the $element attribute the $scope.onButtonClicked() but i am getting the error "Referencing DOM nodes in Angular expressions is disallowed" , what is the way i can pass it ?

Comment: `showAlertMessage` would in the application controller rite ?

Comment: @iJade Yes , showAlertMessage definition should be in the App.js controller, this is to be fired after the directive is done its work of adding the value to the input box